# which string class to use in high performance and to be simple in c++

Tags: c++, string, performance

I'm building a simple framework in c++ , I heard a lot that std::string class is not good in critical performance situations, I'm aware of the problem of copy on return that was fixed in the c++11 by the move constructor for the rvalue reference.

- did the C++11 fixed that issues?? if so then why there is a proposal for string_ref http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3334.html
- Is it recommended to use std::string other than any other string?
- Also the simplicity using std::string by users who all are used to deal with C# is so hard, I decided to provide my string with methods like those in System::String in.NET (I mean the same names , the same scenarios as i know that std and STL provide all functionality I'll need ) if string is good performance how bad the idea of wrapping it inside a custom class that serve the needed functionality? like the following :

.

```
//this is a simple scratch for what I meant by wrapping std::string inside a custom string
class CustomString
{
public:
    CustomString()// : str(nullptr) //shared_ptr will initialize to zero
    {
    }

    CustomString(const char* str)
    {
        str = make_shared<std::string>(str);
    }

    uint32_t IndexOf(char c)
    {
        //call the appropriate methods in the str->find(...
    }

    uint32_t IndexOf(const char* ofStr)
    {
        //call the appropriate methods in the str->find(...
    }

    uint32_t IndexOf(const CustomString& ofStr)
    {
        //call the appropriate methods in the str->find(...
    }

    CustomString SubString(uint32_t start = 0, uint32_t length = -1)
    {
        //call the appropriate methods in the str->substr(...
    }

    CustomString LastIndexOf(const CustonString& str)
    {
        //call the appropriate methods in the str->rfind(...
    }
    //............
    //.......
    //..complete all other needed functionality
    //.does the added in-between method call will have a noticeable  effect on the performance 
private:
    shared_ptr<std::string> str;

};
```

Comment: You have to measure this stuff to see if it makes a difference. Put another way, if you haven't measured then you shouldn't be worrying.

Comment: This smells a lot like premature optimisations. Are you sure that you need another string class?

Comment: @juanchopanza: I haven't measured it but somebody else did in this article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/498251/A-Cplusplus-String-class he has some measurements and comparison between different types of string by applying different operations.

Comment: The reason for the proposal of `string_ref` does not appear to have anything with performance.  It appears to have more to do the being able to implicitly convert types.

Comment: @JustSid: It's not bad to ask the people of high experience before doing what you want to do. and as I mentioned in the previous comment there is a link for some comparison, I wanted to make sure I'm on the right way, but what about the third point of wrapping the std::string inside another class.

Comment: @Zac string_ref is all about performance; the point is that none of the conversions require a copy, whereas constructing a `string` would.

Comment: @AlanStokes:  http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/utility/doc/html/string_ref.html  The efficiency gains are due to the fact that it isn't doing what `std::string` does at all.  It is wrapping a `const char*` and allowing you to pull substrings out of it without making a copy.  It would have a very specific use case, whereas `std::string` is a general purpose tool.

Answer (score 2):

To answer one of your questions:

> Is it recommended to use `std::string` other than any other string?

Yes, it is. If someone else wants to use your framework, then if you use `std::string` they don't have to worry about learning to use a new string class. And most of the time, the performance of `std::string` is quite satisfactory.

EDIT:

A time when you would not want to use `std::string` is when you want to pass a string for some other code to look at, but not touch. Note that strings in c++, unlike strings in .NET, are mutable. For that reason, passing `std::string`s around by value is much more expensive in c++ (because of the copy), so you want to use `const std::string&`.

Another time you don't want to use `std::string` is when you want to write a function that takes a string literal (ie, you need a hardcoded string that you can look at but not edit). For this, you want to use a `const char *`. This is about as efficient as you can get. Also, another c++ programming who looks at your code and sees `const char *` will immediately think "string literal," which makes the code more self-explanatory.

Comment: what about the third part of the question, wrapping the std::string inside a new custom class to provide a simple interface for the developer, for example user will call IndexOf method that will call the find method in the string member, is this idea good? I added some code to the answer to make it more clear about what I meant